# python - Difference between decorator location when returning a function

Tags: python, decorator

Is there a difference between these two location of a decorator ?

```
def a():
    @decorator_function # HERE
    def b():
        pass
    return b

@decorator_function # OR HERE ?
c = a()
```

Comment: There *is* a difference in placing the decorator before `a()` rather than `b()`. But like @BrenBarn says, the second is not valid syntax.

Comment: I can't even figure out what went through my mind when I wrote this question. :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BrenBren said, your code doesn't work.  In any case, first, decorator syntax is just syntactical sugar.

```
@deco
def func():
    pass
```

is equivalent to

```
def func():
    pass
func = deco(func)
```

So even assuming correct syntax, the first example is decorating the enclosed function `b()` while the second would be decorating the closure `a()`.  So:

```
@deco
def a():
    def b():
        pass
```

is the same as

```
def a():
    def b():
        pass
a = deco(a)
```

and

```
def a():
    @deco
    def b():
        pass
```

is the same as

```
def a():
    def b():
        pass
    b = deco(b)
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you even try this?  The second one isn't valid syntax.  So yes, the difference is that the first one is valid and the second one isn't.

Comment: I had a feeling that the second wasn't valid, but I didn't have time to test it.  (+1)

Comment: I tried it with django but it didn't raise any error though it didn't work as well.